# What are some preferred methods to efficiently edit files on a remote Unix server?

Tags: files, editors

I'm looking for a more efficient GUI-based solution to edit root-owned and root-only writable files than using either `nano` or `vim`, both of which of course limit your cursor to navigate one character at a time with very limited cut/copy/paste capabilities.

Some of the methods I've heard of so far have been `rsync`ing files to my local machine and back again, as well as `sshfs`. The tricky part is being able to get to root files without initial logging in as the root user, because root login is, of course, disabled, meaning that I couldn't just SFTP into the machine and make edits over a client.

Comment: "*vim, [...] which of course limit your cursor to navigate one character at a time with very limited cut/copy/paste capabilities.*" -- I would recommend running `vimtutor` and going through it on your local machine. It should take 30 minutes or less. Your statement shows that you clearly have no idea what vim can do.

Comment: My preferred method is simply `sudoedit` over `ssh`.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'll try that. Sorry, I'm still pretty new to this stuff.

Comment: No worries. Vim has a bit of a steep learning curve to turn it from a crappy console Notepad to a real power tool. Not everyone likes it but I would really recommend going through some of the basics so you at least have an idea of what it is capable of.

Comment: The preferred method of editing files, even on a local machine *is* `vim`/`emacs` for many people, including me.